# I'm making a server to receive data via the web with express and node error "RequestError: No connection is specified for that request."

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

im making a server to receive data via the web with express and node but when receiving the data it's giving the following error

I've tried everything to change the port, create another user etc, I know that due to the error the user is giving an error but I don't know how to correct it
if anyone can help me or indicate how to solve it would be very grateful

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\script\uploadDados.js
Servidor iniciado na porta 3000
undefined 1 b c
Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados: ConnectionError: Falha de logon do usuário 'Conexao'.
    at C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1012:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1040:18)
    at C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2519:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {code: 'ELOGIN', originalError: Error: Falha de logon do usuário 'Conexao'…okenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\Users\Eduf…, name: 'ConnectionError', stack: 'ConnectionError: Falha de logon do usuário 'C…ions (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)', message: 'Falha de logon do usuário 'Conexao'.'}
Erro ao executar a consulta: RequestError: No connection is specified for that request.
    at Request._query (C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:493:37)
    at Request._query (C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:363:11)
    at C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:461:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Request.query (C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:460:12)
    at C:\Users\Edufr\OneDrive - Sociedade Educacional do Espírito Santo - UVV\Open_Office_Innovation\Templates\script\uploadDados.js:53:19 {code: 'ENOCONN', name: 'RequestError', stack: 'RequestError: No connection is specified for …ovation\Templates\script\uploadDados.js:53:19', message: 'No connection is specified for that request.'}
Nenhum depurador disponível, não é possível enviar 'variables'
Process exited with code 1
```

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const cors = require('cors');


// Configurações do banco de dados
const dbConfig = {
  user: 'Conexao',
  password: '1',
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'OPEN_I',
  port: 56167,
  options: {
    trustServerCertificate: true, // Somente se estiver usando uma conexão criptografada
  }
};


// Cria uma instância do aplicativo Express
const app = express();
// Abre o cors sem ele da erro o codigo
app.use(cors());
// Middleware para interpretar o corpo da solicitação como JSON
app.use(express.json());

// Configuração da conexão com o banco de dados
async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await sql.connect(dbConfig);
    console.log('Conexão com o banco de dados estabelecida com sucesso.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados:', error);
  }
}

// Rota para realizar uma consulta no banco de dados
app.post('/inserirCadastro', async (req, res) => {
  // Obtém os dados enviados na requisição
  var { nome, cpf, email, password } = req.body;
      console.log(nome + ' ' + cpf + ' ' + email + ' ' + password);
  try {
    // Conecta ao banco de dados
    await connectToDatabase();

    // Insere os dados na tabela PARTICIPANTES
    const sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO PARTICIPANTES (CPF, NOME,MATRICULA, EMAIL, SENHA) VALUES ('@cpf', '@nome',21232323,' @email', '@password)'`;
    const request = new sql.Request();
    request.input('nome', sql.VarChar, nome);
    request.input('cpf', sql.VarChar, cpf);
    request.input('email', sql.VarChar, email);
    request.input('password', sql.VarChar, password);

    await request.query(sqlQuery);

    // Retorna uma mensagem de sucesso
    res.json({ message: 'Dados inseridos com sucesso.' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao executar a consulta:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro ao executar a consulta' });
  }
});
// Inicia o servidor
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor iniciado na porta 3000');
});
```

Comment: So why doesn't it login? Does the instance have an SQL Login named `Conexao`? Does the password (I'm assuming `1` is not the real password) exactly match? (It's case-sensitive.) Does the `OPEN_I` database exist? Does the `Conexao` login have a corresponding database user mapping in the `OPEN_I` database? If you check the instance's Error Log for error 18456 messages can you compare the `State` number(s) displayed there against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to see what the cause is?